# R - Date format check

Tags: r, date-formatting

I am trying to check whether a given date is in dd/mm/yyyy format or not in `R` language and also whether it is a valid date or not at the same time. I want  output in TRUE or FALSE format, e.g.

**Input**:

```
date<- c('12/05/2016','35/11/2067','12/52/1000')
```

**Output**:

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Check if it is NA after conversion to Date: `!is.na(as.Date(date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
IsDate <- function(mydate, date.format = "%d/%m/%y") {
  tryCatch(!is.na(as.Date(mydate, date.format)),  
           error = function(err) {FALSE})  
}

IsDate(date)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Original source of the code [here](https://gist.github.com/micstr/69a64fbd0f5635094a53).

.

Comment: Can you give an example where the `tryCatch` would be doing something?

Comment: date<-NULL
!is.na(as.Date(date, date.format))
Error in as.Date.default(date, date.format) : 
  do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”
IsDate(date)
[1] FALSE

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection: `IsDate("2020-08-05; SELECT * FROM db", "%Y-%M-%d")` is TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
!is.na(parse_date_time(c('12/05/2016','35/11/2067','12/52/1000'),orders="dmy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized base R function that handles `NA`, and is safe against SQL injection:

```r
is_date = function(x, format = NULL) {
  formatted = try(as.Date(x, format), silent = TRUE)
  is_date = as.character(formatted) == x & !is.na(formatted)  # valid and identical to input
  is_date[is.na(x)] = NA  # Insert NA for NA in x
  return(is_date)
}
```

Let's try:

```r
> is_date(c("2020-08-11", "2020-13-32", "2020-08-11; DROP * FROM table", NA), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
## TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```