Creating test for date columns incorrectly throwing error
I want to run a test to verify that all date columns in a df are in the 'ymd' order.
I'm using the code below (data given at the end)
date_stop = function(df_date, date_order){
  
  #get only date columns
  dates_only <- unlist(lapply(df_date, lubridate::is.Date), use.names = FALSE) 
  
  date_cols = df_date[, dates_only]
  
  #check all date columns for correct date order

  stopifnot(
    for (date_col in date_cols){
      !is.na(lubridate::parse_date_time(date_col, orders= date_order)
     )
      }, return(date_cols)
  )
}

date_stop(df, 'ymd')


However, this is throwing a false error Error in date_stop(ccbh, "ymd") :  for (date_col in date_cols) { .... are not all TRUE, because if I run these columns individually, they all have the correct format. Is there something I'm missing?
I also noticed something weird with stopifnot in that I can't pipe into it; for instance, with the data below, this does not work date_cols%>%stopifnot(Date_opened == Date_opened) but this does stopifnot(date_cols$Date_opened == date_cols$Date_opened) Why is that?
df = structure(list(Dob = structure(c(13004, 12040), class = "Date"), 
    Date_opened = structure(c(19465, 19299), class = "Date"), 
    Date_closed = structure(c(19541, 19710), class = "Date"), 
    Date_closed_original = structure(c(19541, 19710), class = "Date"), 
    Date_closed_fy = structure(c(19541, 19710), class = "Date"), 
    other = c(14, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))


It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Your sample data are already date class, these are stored internally as integers and represented as "YYYY-MM-DD" when they are printed - so trying to reparse them using parse_date_time() is wholly redundant as you've already checked that these are dates using is.Date().  Parsing is for character representations of dates not for objects that are already date class.

Yeah, I was just trying to include as little date as possible. I have updated the date to include another column that is not date, so the is.Date() pulls in only those columns that are dates, and the parse_date-time checks that they follow the correct ymd. If they were in myd, they would still be dates, correct? If that is not the case, then the is.Date() should more generally check that they are dates vs numeric, etc.

You could also run diff on each column to see if any resulting in negative changes, i.e. going in reverse chronological order. cols <- colnames(df[,-1]); lapply(df[cols], diff) |> as.numeric() |> min() will yield a negative number if any columns are in reverse chronological order.

Dates in R cannot be in myd or dmy -- they are by definition in YYYY-MM-DD. Otherwise they are characters that represent to humans a date. "Date" is a numeric class which prints as YYYY-MM-DD, but can be transformed to character data in any arbitrary date format.

Ah, I see. Thanks for that. I can delete the question if that is best. But shouldn't the function still work with the forloop? I don't understand why it is throwing an error? (Just trying to deepen my understanding). Also, not sure why I can't pipe into stopifnot?

@James does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542804/r-date-format-check

I agree with the comments that there is no need to test the format of a numeric date, it is always YYYY-MM-DD.
To answer the question about the stopifnot(), you have stopifnot() testing the value returned by the for loop, which returns NULL. If you move the stopifnot() inside the loop to test each column, the loop will complete with your example data.
for (date_col in date_cols){
  stopifnot(!is.na(lubridate::parse_date_time(date_col, orders= date_order)
  ))
}

